# How to load images on Heroku (Django deployed app)

Tags: django, image, heroku

I've just recently deployed my Django application using heroku, and have an issue where the profile pictures in my blog website don't save (ends up being an image that never loads).

Is there any way I can solve this (and if so, without using Amazon S3)?

I want to avoid Amazon S3 if possible.

Is there anyway or alternatives to implement images into my Heroku website?

Comment: "I want to avoid Amazon S3 if possible"—why? Do you specifically want to avoid S3, or all third-party image hosts? Are the images uploaded by users? If so you'll need _some_ third-party host for them.

Comment: Yes, they'll be uploaded by users as it's a blog-type website where they can upload profile pictures.

Comment: Then you _must_ use a third-party image host. That can be Amazon S3, or any of a number of other services.

Comment: Yeah, I want to use another one other than Amazon S3, but since I'm quite new to this all I can't find tutorials to how to utilize other ones than Amazon S3

Comment: What's wrong with Amazon S3? We can't help you if we don't know what you don't like about it. (But be careful to stay on-topic. Don't ask us to find or recommend an alternative to S3, and make sure your question isn't too broad. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].)

Comment: A user here recommended using Cloudinary as an alternative, which might actually be a good idea looking at it.

Comment: I'd still like to know (this is the third time I'm asking) what you don't like about Amazon S3. Questions and answers here are meant to help future users as well as the people asking right now. If you could explain why you want to avoid S3 it might help round out the question.

Comment: I simply don't have good experience using it. I've used it in the past multiple times and it didn't seem to work well with a lot of my projects, which is why I'm currently looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration) for a django blog on heroku. The api allows you to upload and display images quite easily.

Comment: So I'm extremely new to Django and Heroku, how do I go about utilizing this in my already deployed Heroku app? Or do I need to re-deploy?

Comment: If all your hosting is through Cloudinary you will need to update your code and re-deploy. I used Cloudinary because heroku has very limited space, but you should still be able to display some static files in your heroku app. If that's the case, you might want to post the relevant code so we can help you better

Comment: Essentially, I created a blog where users can upload profile pictures. So to install Cloudinary into Heroku do I just type "heroku addons:create cloudinary:starter" into my terminal?

Comment: Yes you will need to install Cloudinary through your terminal, but in order for it to work, you will need to update your settings, upload system, and templates to point to the correct file location; the Cloudinary api using your key/secret key once you have created an account. There a number of examples included in that link that you can follow along with

Comment: Ahhh, I'm still extremely new to Django so I'm sorry for the questions. I installed Cloudinary through my terminal, made an account, but am unsure which templates to update or where to put the cloudinary config.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to serve the images using static files. Also, you will need to install WhiteNoise, which will serve the static files on Heroku. For the short-term this should be fine, however, for the long term, it is recommended that you use a cloud-based service.

This link is the main guide:
https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/Heroku_Django_Deployment_Guide.md

I would recommend going through the references also.
These would be the references:

1) http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

2) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

3) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static

I ran into the same problem you ran into. Following the steps in the guide and references worked well for me.